# android:how to search row by edittext(searchbar) in ListView

Tags: android

I want to search relevant `Row` in List views rows which type in `edittext` contents.

How can i get row in `Listview`..please give me example Code..

Thanks

Comment: Thanks hardik. Your question helps me.

Comment: I have understand the Search Functionality. But what can we do if we have implement the custom arrayAdapter ?

Comment: Meet me in casual chat please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that you want to search items from listview based on the edittext value you type.

Here is an example: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-searchbox-sort-items

Comment: hi paresh, I am not able to open the link you have provided(some url's are blocked in our office). can you please provide stuff from that post and update it in your answer. it would be really helpfull.